# Getting WebAssembly running

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I'm trying to get WebAssembly's polyfill-prototype-1 running:

I have a localhost running a .html file with only the basics (   ) and a call to loadWebAssembly() as specified in https://github.com/WebAssembly/polyfill-prototype-1/blob/master/README.md.

However, when I go to the page I get the error: "http://localhost/-username-/polyfill-prototype-1/undefined 404 (Not Found)" because packedURL in load-wasm.js is undefined, which as seen in the afore-cited link, seems to mean that step 2 in "How it (currently) works" (i.e. "The polyfill library starts up a worker containing asm.js code compiled from unpack.cpp concatenated with the glue code in load-wasm-worker.js.") Isn't being called/run/something

I've speculated that I'm not giving it the path to the code to convert or something, but I don't know how to do so.

What am I doing wrong/how do I get it to turn my c++ code into asm.js so it can continue to step 3?

Answer (score 5):

Following this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-started-with-webassembly-using-only-14-lines-of-javascript-b37b6aaca1e4/) for this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lordpoint/wasm-demo) running locally in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WASM\Index.html, in IIS I converted the directory to an application and get a **404 Not Found** for squarer.wasm when browsing to http://localhost/WASM/Index.html

The error is shown in the Browser Developer Tools console:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
>   (Fetch)GET - http://localhost/wasm/squarer.wasm

To get rid of the 404 add a new Mime Type for Wasm, it's not currently in IIS 10 (or below).

Click Start > Run > type InetMgr > expand Sites > select the app > Mime Types > Add:

Extension: **.wasm**  (dot wasm)
MIMEType:  **application/wasm**

Ref: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/229